# How do I delete HTML5 game apps in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed the new Chrome store today and downloaded / installed the free app "Canvas Rider".

I quickly determined that the game was both difficult to control, and frustratingly unforgiveably hard.

I decided that I would unistall the app and never speak of my lack of skills regarding it immediately... except I can't figure out how to uninstall it!

Where is the application data saved / how do I rid myself of this (now) unwanted app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't change Chrome homepage you can open a new tab, which will show your apps and most visited sites.

**You can right click on desired app and there choose the remove option in the context menu. Or you can drag your app to the thrash can that will appear in bottom right corner when you drag them.**

Wrench icon > Options > Basics> On startup: open the homepage (in case you changed homepage and suffered amnesia).

Comment: Aha! Right-click the element itself. Thanks!